# Why does my PHP PDO function to insert one MySQL record loop without end?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

All,

I'm trying the code below, and I think that as I have written it, the value of `$inserted` never becomes `TRUE`, I am not sure why.  When I run the program, I get thousands of empty records created, and I have to manually shut down the server.

```
function createRecord(){ // Query creates a new empty record in table, returns the auto-incremented ID.
            $dbConnection=$this->dbConnect();
            $inserted=false;
            $IDQuery=null;
            while (!$inserted){
                $insertQuery=$dbConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO $this->table () VALUES ()");
                $inserted=$insertQuery->execute();
                if ($inserted){
                    $IDQuery=$dbConnection->prepare("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
                    $IDQuery->execute();
                }
            }
            $result=$IDQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $ID=$result["Last_Insert_ID()"];
            return $ID;
        }
```

Many thanks in helping me with this.

Cheers,

JDelage

EDIT: I can't recreate the problem on a stand alone piece of code, so I think the problem is not related to this part of the code.

Comment: OK, one thing I have noticed after running tests is that `"Last_Insert_ID()"` needs to be capitalized into `"LAST_INSERT_ID()"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of running a query for the last insert id you should use PDO::last_insert_id.

http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.lastinsertid.php

I'm not sure why you'd need to use the loop to insert your row. Try and inspect the prepared and executed statement with `debugDumpParams()`, you may want to use `bindParam()` for the prepared statement also instead of injecting the variables into the string like that.

Edit: Did you make sure that the table you are trying to insert to has a column set for AUTO_INCREMENT? Otherwise the PDO driver will not return meaningful data for `last_insert_id()`.

Comment: I'll check out the `PDO::last_insert_id` and `debugDumpParams()`, I am not familiar with them.  Thanks for bringing them to my attention.  Any suggestion on why `$inserted` stays false?

Comment: I recreated your code and the missing `dbConnect()` method, but I cannot reproduce that problem. Check your table structure, make sure you have an index for a column and that column is set for `AUTO_INCREMENT`. It's the only thing I can think of at this point, I'd need to see more of your code to help further. The `$inserted` variable is set to true on the first cycle of the loop on my end. The problem seems to lie elsewhere than in the shown code snippet.

Comment: why is it better to use `PDO::last_insert_id` rather than the MySQL function?  Is it just to have a more db-agnostic code?